# Cómo cambiar la razón entre los ejes X y Y en LaTex

Tags: latex

Necesito cambiar la razón entre los eje X y Y de 1:1 a 1:2, es decir necesito que los valores en el eje y vayan de dos en dos y los del eje x se mantengan iguales. Lo necesito porqué una de mis gráficas es demasiado larga en el eje y.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Miren mi código:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.72]
        \draw [->](-5,0) -- (5,0) node[below] {$x$};
        \draw [->](0,-7) -- (0,5) node[right] {$y$};
        \foreach \y in {-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5}
        \draw (0,\y) -- (-0.1,\y) node[left,scale=0.7] {\y};
        \foreach \x in {-5,-3,-1,1,3}
        \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.1) node[below,scale=0.7] {\x};
        \clip (-5,-7) rectangle (5,5);
        \draw[color=olive,thick, domain=-5:5,smooth, samples=29] plot (\x, {pow(\x,4)+4*pow(\x,3)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede usar esta sintaxis, similar a la suya:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=0.72]
```

Además:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=10mm,y=7.2mm]
```

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)